# ReactJS Cortex Object updated by render not invoked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mquan-cortex

I am trying to implement Emberjs's Todo app as a practice exercise for Cortex by mquan on github. I am currently implementing the "All", "Active", "Completed" filter where clicking an anchor will result in the anchor being highlighted (class added).

I created the following:

```
var filtercortex = new cortex([
    {title:'all', selected:true, key:1},
    {title:'completed', selected:false, key:2},
    {title:'active', selected:false, key:3}
]);
```

With the following render function (in the parent):

```
  render: function() {
    var filters = filterCortex.map(function(filter) {
      return (
        <li>
          <FilterAnchor cortex={filterCortex} filter={filter} />
        </li>
      )
    });
    ...

    return ...
          <ul id='filters'>
            {filters}
          </ul>
```

And FilterAnchor's definition:

```
var FilterAnchor = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function() {
    var that = this;
    this.props.cortex.forEach(function(filter) {
      if (filter.key.getValue() == that.props.filter.key.getValue()) {
        console.log(filter.title.getValue(), true);
        filter.selected.set(true);
      } else {
        console.log(filter.title.getValue(), false);
        filter.selected.set(false);
      }
    });
    return false;
  },

  render: function() {
    var className = (this.props.filter.selected.getValue()) ? 'selected' : '';
    return (
      <a className={className} href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.props.filter.title.getValue()}
      </a>
    )
  }
});
```

right now, I do not see the class 'selected' being applied to the anchor links when I am clicking.

However, upon investigation I notice this:

```
Clicking "All":
All true 
Completed false
Active false 

Clicking "Completed":
All true 
Completed false
Active false
```

So I am certain that the objects inside `filtercortex` has been updated properly (you can open up firebug to check). However, `FilterAnchor.render` is **not** being triggered.

Is this a bug?

**Source code: https://github.com/vicngtor/ReactTodo/blob/cortex/script.jsx**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample at the top of the [Cortex readme](https://github.com/mquan/cortex) has this at the bottom:

```
orderCortex.on("update", function(updatedOrder) {
  orderComponent.setProps({order: updatedOrder});
});
```

Is there an equivalent section in your code? If not, then the problem is that the update event for the cortex data store isn't set to trigger an update of the view, which is made through a call to setProps on the top level React component in this example.